# Why is the French Wikipedia of Tchernobyl plant stating the the power is of 1000 MW while English version states that this is 3200 MW?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

The power of a given reactor for the Tchernobyl plant is, according to Wikipedia : 3200 MW (12800 /4 reactors)

Reference :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_Nuclear_Power_Plant

"Reactors   4"

"Thermal capacity   12,800 MW"

Why is the corresponding French Wikipedia stating the the power is of 1000 MW ?

Reference : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrale_nucl%C3%A9aire_de_Tchernobyl

"Puissance nominale     4 × 1 000 MW"

Comment: Thermal power vs electricity produced?

Comment: @Jon Custer : thank you. This is much probably the explanation. For wikipedia english, they write explicitely "thermal capacity : ... MW ". For the french one, they don't give more explanation, but in the text, they write "puissance électrique de 1 000 mégawatts chacun", meaning "electric power of 1000 MW each". Thank you very much.

Comment: @jon-custer provided the correct answer